# Static method not being called Java

Tags: java, static-methods

Since the main method is static, it should be able to be called statically. Therefore, I use:

```
package prototype.server.main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import prototype.server.main.gui.Swing;

public class Runtime {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
            Swing swing = new Swing(true, argv[0]);

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            JFrame maingui = swing.getGuiFrame();
    }
}
```

as the static-main code, then call using:

```
import prototype.server.main.Runtime;

public class Main {
     Runtime.main(new String{"f"});
}
```

to call the static method, but Eclipse is giving me an error. Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: And the error it gives you is.....? Because right now you're calling a method that takes an array of Strings, with "not an array of Strings", so getting an error makes a whole lot of sense. Also why would you use `new String{"f"}` when `"f"` is already that very thing?

Comment: Whats the error

Comment: Your method call is neither inside a method, nor inside a static initialiser block.  That's what you need to fix.

Comment: What is `new String{"f"}`? Perhaps you meant `new String[]{"f"}`?

Comment: To update/clarify your question use [edit] option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two bugs we need to fix;

```
    import prototype.server.main.Runtime;

public class Main {
// add constructor, or method that you can call another method
// or make this static { ... } block that fits you
public Main() {
//do not forget [] for array
     Runtime.main(new String[]{"f"});
}
}
```

Comment: All I needed was main method, but constuctor is close enough, Thanks for your help!